# Getting a string between 2 defined patterns with an end of line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

The file under test will have text patterns like this:

```
name1: function(){

},
 name2: function(){

},
 name3: function(){

},
```

I need to get "name1" "name2" and "name3" in this example.
So used this bash script:

```
v1='},'
v2=': function'
sed 's/'"$v1"'\(.*\)'"$v2"'/\1/g' test1.js > newfile2
```

This seems to work only if the pattern shows up like:

```
 },name1: function
```

But of course the text file is not formatted this way. it's like this:

```
 },
name1: function
```

What should I add to the regex that would accomplish what i need?
I do not want to change from using `sed`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/\s*\([^: ]*\): function.*/\1/p' test1.js
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep function your_file|awk -F":" '{print $1}'
```